# Passing a function with parameters to NIntegrate

Tags: functions, parameters

I have a function that serves as an integrand, but has a function `f[q]` as a parameter:

```
integrand[f_, Ω_, q_, d_] := 
  q^2 (E^(-0.5 (q d/2)^2) / (f[q] ((Ω - f[q])^2 + (Γ/2)^2)))
```

It gets plugged into an integral that washes away the q dependence:

```
intensity[??, Ω, d] :=  NIntegrate[integrandFunc[Ω], q, d], {q, 0, 1}];
```

I don't know what my parameters should be in the intensity function. [This stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545113/function-of-a-function) lets me know that if function `g[c]` depends on `f[a, b]`, then `g` should be declared as `g[f, a, b, c]`. With my intensity function above, it depends on that original input function `f[q]` in a sense, but then it doesn't depend on `q` since `q` is integrated away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
integrand[f_, Ω_, q_, d_, Γ_] := q^2*(E^(-0.5*(q*d/2)^2)/(f[q] ((Ω - f[q])^2 + (Γ/2)^2)))
intensity[f_, Ω_, d_, Γ_] := NIntegrate[integrand[f, Ω, q, d, Γ], {q, 0, 1}]
intensity[# &, 0, 0, 1]
```

> 0.804719

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Perhaps this is unrelated, but when I try to plot intensity:

`Plot[intensity[tran111, Ω, 3.1,10] , {Ω, 270, 330}, PlotRange -> Full`, I get the error

"NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand ... has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}."

However, when I plot the intensity as a function of d, holding Ω constant, its is perfectly happy to plot. 
`Plot[intensity[tran111, 300,d,10] , {d, 2, 20}, PlotRange -> Full]`

I hope you didn't get notified _every time_ I accidentally hit enter instead of shift+enter.

Comment: @Roy What is `tran111`? I guess really, what is the integrand that it shows in the error message?  My guess is `tran111` makes the denominator of `integrand` zero at some `q` (either by being zero manifestly, or otherwise).  This also explain why there are no errors when you plot over `d` because `d` doesn't influence the denominator.

Comment: It turned out it was due to an undeclared variable. Thanks again for the help.